# What happens with this use of the .map() function from Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, function, interface

I have a question about the .map() function which can be used on arrays.

The normal usage I know is like:

```
function myFunction(num) {
  return num * 2;
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const newArr = numbers.map((element) => myFunction(element))
```

But in a code sample I saw the following usage:

```
const resultToRow = (r: MyProductsDto) => ({
  rowData: tableColumns.map(() => r),
});
```

In this example *MyProductsDto* is an Interface and *tableColumns* is an Array.
But what exactly does `.map(() => r)` ?

**r** is not a function but a Interface and why is the arrow function empty without any arguments?

Comment: It simply returns the same value `r` for each array element.

Comment: keep in mind that if `r` is an object, this will assign a reference to the same object to each index of `tableColumns`. (thus changing one will change them all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As length as of tableColumns, there will be r[] in `rowData`

also it all the value of `r[]` will be same because it has one reference address.

r[0] === r[1] === [r2] === [r(n)]

map makes new array from original array each element will pass as argument but accept it (the argument that tossed by map) or not is not consideration of `map` it just makes new array with return value of given function.

Comment: Thank you, that is currently the case! Is this some kind of a special case of .map() ? Does it have a name? Because in all the explanations and tutorials I saw, there wasnt any use case similar to this one

Comment: @tbastue Since i worked as web developer  for 5years i never saw that case. :)  Also there will other good way to make r array. so i will never write code like that.

Comment: new Array(tableColumns.length).fill(r) will be same...